# How to generate a grub2 menuentry with update-grub for an encrypted zfs root filesystem?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, encryption, zfs

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on ZFS 0.8.4 and am playing around with encryption. I'd like to have a menuentry in grub that lets me boot to the encrypted root.

#### System Setup

A checkmark indicates that there is a corresponding menu entry in grub.

- `aquarium/ds1/u18` ✓
  contains my ubuntu 18.04 and has its mountpoint set to `/`
- `tank/ds1/u18`
  is copied from `aquarium` with the sole difference being that `ds1` is encrypted and `u18` inherits that property.
- Windows 10 ✓
  I hope it doesn't have anything to do with my issues though.
- `/dev/nvme0n1p8` ✓
  An EXT4-formatted system that is still there from when I switched to the ZFS `aquarium`

I have an EXT2 partition for `/boot` and another partition for `/boot/efi`.

#### Manual Workarounds

When I select and edit the `aquarium` entry by replacing `root=ZFS=aquarium/ds1/u18` with `root=ZFS=tank/ds1/u18` I can boot fine into initramfs where I am prompted for the passphrase. After entering the passphrase, I get my system as expected.

Inside that system (or any other ubuntu system for that matter), I can create a custom entry in `/etc/grub/40_custom`.

```
menuentry "Encryptioned Magic 18.04" {
    linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-51-generic root=ZFS=tank/ds1/u18 ro acpi_backlight=video resume=UUID-OF-SWAP-PARTITION
    initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-51-generic
}
```

I'd like to avoid this, because a manual entry means I need to modify it when the UUID of my swap filesystem changes, or something else. I mean, all the reasons why we don't create custom entries for every OS basically also apply here.

#### Solution Attempt

Ideally, this would use `sudo update-grub`, but even with the encryption key loaded or even when I am within the encrypted system, it doesn't seem to find it. This log is from running it in `aquarium`.

```
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub`
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/poly-dark/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (18.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p8
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

When I run this same command in the encrypted `tank` system, I get additionally a message between the second `Found initrd image` and the `Found Windows Boot Manager` lines:

```
device-mapper: reload ioctl on osprober-linux-nvme0n1p10   failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed
```

The mentioned partition `nvme0n1p10` is the single partition where the pool `tank` with the encrypted dataset `tank/ds1/u18` is set up on.

This same error message seems to happen whenever `zfs` is using a partition when I run `update-grub` [since it opens it for exclusive access](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/9801), no matter which system I'm logged into. This behaviour is a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober/+bug/1848496) in os-prober but they call it

> not actually failing, just spewing errors during os-prober. We want to clean it up (it is cosmetic).

**How can I autogenerate a grub entry for my encrypted zfs dataset?**

Comment: Maybe the message and the problem are unrelated. In some other context, it seems to be a not important error: [github issue](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/9801)

Comment: Related zfs grub issue [on github](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/grub/issues/18#issuecomment-645355221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently still an [open issue](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/grub/issues/18#issuecomment-656024216) at zfsonlinux/grub but I have posted a workaround there (and here) thanks to the github user [tterpelle](https://github.com/tterpelle):

What we are going to do is grabbing the grub scripts from Ubuntu 19.04 for our Ubuntu 18.04.

1. > Download `grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu12_amd64.deb` from https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/grub-common/download and extract it with `ar x grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu12_amd64.deb`.
2. Get the `/etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs` file out of that `data.tar.xz`.
   I didn't know the correct way so I just did `vim data.tar.xz`, opened the file, then did `:w 10_linux_zfs`.
3. Move it to `/etc/grub.d`
4. Make it executable as it may not be run otherwise.
   `sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs`
5. `sudo update-grub`

This suffices to generate a correct entry. But we also want not to have any incorrect entries, so we have to replace `10_linux` in the same way because they added a few lines that skip generation of zfs entries in there.

> ```
>    # We have a more specialized ZFS handler, with multiple system in 10_linux_zfs.
>    if [ -e "`dirname $(readlink -f $0)`/10_linux_zfs" ]; then
>      exit 0
> ```

6. repeat steps 2) to 5) for `10_linux` instead of `10_linux_zfs`.

Comment: Update a year and a half later: this is still working for me, and when an update wants to change these files it is so kind to ask me first whether it's okay.